# Spring data JPA and JdbcTemplate are not synchronous

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-jdbc

Im experiencing a problem with jdbcTemplate and JPA:

```
    public void test(){

     //assuming we have 3k users and use jdbcTemplate to perform batch update

     batchUpdateUsers(userList) ;
     //This list doesn't contain latest information of user after update
     List<User>updatedUsers = userRepository.findAll();
}
```

I guess after method **batchUpdateUsers** return, transaction was not committed or it has already been committed but there's delaying time to commit it to DB so the the fetched list later is not updated.

Is there any way to solve this problem? Thanks!

Comment: There is too little information (code and configuration) here to help you. It should work if you setup it correctly.

Comment: FWIW Spring Data JPA != JPA API. Tags now fixed, so please tag correctly in future

Comment: @meobeo173 I didn't forget anything. You need to provide more information / context then what you have now.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a transaction issue. If you declare a JpaTransactionManager and have a single Datasource, modifications made by `batchUpdateUsers` should be visible by `userRepository.findAll`

How do you manage transactions?  If you are using Spring Boot look at `@EnableTransactionManagement` and `@Transactional` annotations.